# How to install jquery dotdotdot plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, jquery, uploads, wp-enqueue-script, installation

I need to download jquery dotodotdot plugin. I downloaded the .zip file and tried uploading it but it gave me the message

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.
>
> Plugin install failed.

Here is the link for the website- http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

How can I install this?

Comment: when you download the plugin, unzip it first before uploading. sometimes the actual plugin is inside the zip.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out that plugin. It's not a WordPress plugin, so that error is only normal. Rather, it's a [jquery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/dotdotdot/). You would include it as part of a (child) theme  or plugin. Unzip it and put the files in the src directory it in a subdirectory of your theme/plugin.

Then use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to include it in your project in stead of putting it directly in the head of the page, as the site you link to instructs. That link also shows how to use the script in your pages.

UPDATE after comments

In the unzipped folder find the file `jquery.dotdotdot.js`. Put it in a folder called `js` in your child theme.

In your child theme's `functions.php` add:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse240448_dotdotdot');
function wpse240448_dotdotdot () {
  wp_register_script('dotdotdot', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.dotdotdot.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('dotdotdot');
  $script = '$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#wrapper").dotdotdot({
        //  configuration goes here according to your link
    });
   });
  '; 
  wp_add_inline_script ('dotdotdot',$script);
  }
```

Comment: Alright that clears stuff up, but how would I go on about " Unziping it and putting it in a subdirectory of your theme/plugin?"

Comment: Are you developing a theme or a plugin?

Comment: Im just trying to use the dotdotdot plugin for a page of my website.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of how to create a child theme or plugin? Because that's what you'll need to do to insert a piece of code into your site, since the is no prefab WP plugin that includes dotdotdot for you.

Comment: I already have a child theme that I am using and no I don't know how to create a plugin.

Comment: Ok, so you can add this to your child theme. I'll update my answer

Comment: Another problem came up, when I go to appearance> editor I dont have the option to edit my js folder. Do I need to go to my FTP database?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use ftp to add that script file to your child theme.